# display 2 icon in the same position using css?

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE...

```
          <ul class="social-icon">
            <li><a href="#" class="social-facebook">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-facebook ff"></i>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-dribbble"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="social-rss"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
```

CSS CODE..

```
.social-icon {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-icon li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.social-icon li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 38px;
  width: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.social-icon li a i {
  color: #d2d2db;
}
```

I want to display this two icon in same position like one icon...Please Help me. Sorry for my Bad English. 
[Here is jsfiddle editor link](http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/34/)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to have two icons in the same position? This seems like it could be accomplished in other ways.

Comment: i want to use two icon in same position for a hover effect. That's impossible without two icon.

Comment: @MannfromReno Same but little bit different.

Comment: @Hanif If it truly is different, it would help to describe *how* it is different. Looks very much the same to me.

Comment: first problem was two icon in same position problem...and the second problem was... two icon in same position with border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want. right?

http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/39/

```
 I just add:
 position:absolute;
```

Comment: and some other little values for positioning and li height

Answer (score 1):

If your require 2 icons for a hover effect you should do something like this;

```
a { background: url(/image1.png) no-repeat 0 0;}

a:hover{ background: url(/image2.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just add this code along with others:

```
 .social-icon li{ position:relative; }

 .social-icon li a i {
        color: #d2d2db;
        position:absolute;
        left:10px;
        top:4px;
  }
```

Check and let me know. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/38/

Comment: Thanks but the box problem???

Comment: What problem, tell me in detail.

Comment: Please check the fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/40/ are you speaking for without box ?

Comment: Please check  i want like this.. http://jsfiddle.net/2N2YF/39/